# Accessing Drupal database for read purposes

Tags: database

I'm interested in analyzing various aspects of the content in our Drupal site involving node meta data such as type, name, creation date, etc. I know I can create views to show some informaiton and I know I can dump out the database and analyze it separately, but I'd really like to query the database live (for read purposes only) from a remote machine so that I can use the software of my choice to do the analysis, reporting, etc.

Does Drupal have a remotely accessible API that I can use query its database?

(Note: I suspect the "db-api" tag is inappropriate for this question, but I couldn't figure out anything else to use.)

Comment: Why can't you connect directly to MySQL / Postgres?

Comment: That's possible, but while I've been given admin privileges in Drupal so that I can do some limited admin functions, the site is being maintained by someone else and I have no idea whether the database is configured to be remotely accessible. I was also hoping to avoid raw SQL if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

- you want to programatically work with data,
- reading them is enough,
- you don't have direct DB access (which is not such a good idea anyways, for security reasons - you'd have to set up SSL tunnels to access the DB), and
- you can dig all the data you need using Views (you can always create some custom module to dig data which Views wouldn't have direct support),

I would suggest using [Services Views](https://drupal.org/project/services_views) module. Services Views turns a View into REST service endpoint. You can then query LIVE data you need from an external application. For enhanced security the endpoint (and service authentication, etc.) should be wrapped in HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks, David. This does look to be the most promising. One question: When I followed the link, it appears that there's only a "development" version for the Drupal 6. Do you know if they are going to be "releasing" a version for Drupal 6 any time soon?

Comment: From the [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/services_views?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=6.x&component=All) of the module, it seems that some work on [porting features](https://drupal.org/node/1661568) from D7 to D6 version was done. Also there is a number of sites reporting usage of D6 version of the module. Unfortunately I can't confirm the state of D6 version, we've used only D7 version. Nevertheless I think it's worth a try :-).

Answer (score 1):

If you want easily importable data, consider using [Views data export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export):

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft XLS
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - XML

You can import CSV or XML to pretty much any data analysis tool you may need.

Comment: Thanks, but I really need the data to be live.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin what do you mean "live"? You are not forced to cache views data. The fact it will be refreshed on request? SQL queries are no more live anyway.

Comment: I apologize. I made a bad assumption that this was something that just exported locally. After looking into it, I see that you can create a display with its own path for getting to the data via the web. I think I still prefer the Services Views approach, but +1 for the answer.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin no need to apologize. Services are more flexible and powerful all right. Views Data Export is simpler to set up. Depends on particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

In the views UI settings, you can check an option in this url :

> admin/structure/views/settings
>
> check "Show the SQL query"

So, in the view's UI live preview, you can copy/paste and re-use theses queries in another code

It is maybe not the best way but it is one, and you do not have to write complex queries joins, views UI do it for you

Theses queries can be executed from anywhere (even directly in mysql), without the drupal boostrap

Comment: The SQL from Views isn't always accurate anymore.  Some views results are built up after doing an entity_load_multiple(), and then using the Field API to get data.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to address the need to be able to retrieve the data from a remote machine.